# Is it possible to change the query text on quick open with an extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'd like to create my own VSCode extension. When users stop typing something in the quick open input, I want to change the text with something else and quick open will use this new text to search for files to open.

For example, user types "foo-bar". I'd like to replace "-" with a whitespace and let the search use "foo bar" to search for files.

Does VSCode provide APIs to change the quick open this way?

I checked the documentation but I was not able to find some useful API method to do that.

Comment: 1) finish typing something _where_ in the editor? in the quick open input? 2) And how do you qualify "finish typing something"? debounce of inactivity?

Comment: 1. Finish typing something in the quickopen input.
2. User stops typing.

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them.

Comment: but how to detect the user has stopped typing, I sometimes think what other word could be part of the file(name), then the tool takes over while I'm not finished typing, if you have not initiated the Quick Input you don't have call backs for the change event

Comment: Are you populating the QuickPick with items yourself or just using the built-in QuickPick for files?